# Quick Order form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

We are trying to create a quick order form where a client inputs an item SKU and its quantity, then tabs down to the next row and does the same. Upon tabbing to the quantity input, we need to have jQuery run a check against our database to ensure that is a real SKU and respond with a success or fail message to the client. We have looked at various codes and have found those that work by adding a new row and by checking against a single input, but we cannot find nor am able to write the code that allows for both. Not sure if we can allow for the input to have its name attribute use "name[]" or if it needs a set name, "name_1", "name_2", etc. If we use name[], how does the call to the database know which inut field to use to get the variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please see our code to date below:

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Quick Order</td>
   </tr>
  <tr class="person">
     <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="nameClass" placeholder="Item ID" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qtyClass" placeholder="QTY" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="person">
     <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="nameClass" placeholder="Item ID" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="qtyClass" placeholder="QTY" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable tbody>tr:last .nameClass").change(function() {
      $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last').hide().fadeIn(500);
      $('#mytable tbody>tr:last .nameClass').val('');
      return false;
    });  // change Function

    $('.nameClass').blur(item_check);
    //});

}); // doc ready

function item_check(){  
    var itemid = $('.nameClass').val();
    //console.log(itemid);
    jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "checkItem.php",
     data: 'itemid='+ itemid,
     cache: false,
     success: function(response){
        if(response == 1){
            $('.nameClass').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');    
        }else{
            $('.nameClass').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
        }

    }
});
} // end function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure if we can allow for the input to have its name attribute use "name[]" or if it needs a set name, "name_1", "name_2", etc. If we use name[], how does the call to the database know which inut field to use to get the variable.

Generally when you attach an event to an input, the input in question is easy to identify using the "this" variable. You don't even really need to know the input's name then.

Also, since you are working with a variable number of rows, you should probably be looking at  [jQuery's on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle events.  For example ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RAsHm/)):

```
var my_table = $('#mytable');

// Whenever the last .nameClass input in the table gains focus, clone that row
my_table.on('focus', '.nameClass:last', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var new_row = input.closest('tr').clone();
    $('input', new_row).val(''); // set blank input values for the cloned row
    $('tbody', my_table).append(new_row);
});

// When a .nameClass input loses focus, check that the SKU in it (if any) is valid
my_table.on('blur', '.nameClass', function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var itemid = $.trim(input.val());
    if (itemid) {
        // Replace demo code with appropriate $.ajax call
        if (itemid == 'fail') {
            input.css('border', '3px #C33 solid');
        } else {
            input.css('border', '3px #090 solid');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you behic for enlightening us on jQuery's on() method and providing the sample code.